# Unity apple/google ID access?

Tags: unity, android, ios

After extensive Googleing I have not come up with a way to access Apple ID's or Google ID's from unity running in respective devices. Either ID's or something else unique to the accounts logged in.

I dunno if this is possible with unity or maybe a plugin exists. If not how would you go about getting this.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-deviceUniqueIdentifier.html

Comment: I had not found this I will give it a read thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this is per device. which is all good but I need it to be Account logged into device so that the user can switch devices and not lose progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the Google play games and Apple Game Center plugins to allow player login to their accounts. Once they do you get their unique id which can be used to store the game progress.

Integrating such plugins have been always a big pain for me, I always prefer Prime 31 but its not free . Link:- https://prime31.com/plugins - Play Game Services Combo - 140$

Currently you have free options , for apple game center. There are unity's inbuilt apis which can be used. Link :- http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/net-SocialAPI.html

And google has already launched an open source plugin for unity. Link :- https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

You also have plenty of other options on the asset store.